# How to extract values from the '-' seperated string in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, string, split

I have a function in VB.Net which takes two arguments(`dosage` & `no_days`).
'dosage' have values of the `1-2-1` format.
I need to get the values as integer from the string: for example, if the string is `1-1-2`, I need to get the values as `1`,`1`,`2`. And sum of these three numbers need to multiply with `no_days` and return the result.
I need to know how can I split the string using regex `"-"`  or any other logic for doing this.

```
Public Function calculateNoOfPeices(ByVal dosage As String, ByVal days As Integer) As String
    Dim noOfPiece As Double = 0.0
    If txt_dosage.Text.Length > 4 Then

        ' need logic to extract the values from the dosage
        'and need to multiply with no_days

    Else
        'lbl_notif.Visible = False
        noOfPiece = "-1"
    End If

    Return noOfPiece.ToString

End Function
```

Please help.

Comment: If you really need a regex; use this: `/(\d+)(-|$)/g` ;).

Comment: @SamAxe this is a portal to learn/help. it doesn't matter who develop what. expecting some manners in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using String.Split**

```
    Dim dosage As String = "1-2-1"
    Dim IntValues() As String = dosage.Split("-")
    Dim fValue As Double = Val(IntValues(0))
    Dim sValue As Double = Val(IntValues(1))
    Dim tValue As Double = Val(IntValues(2))
```

**Using Regx**

```
    Dim pattern As String = "-"
    Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(dosage, pattern)
    Dim fValueR As Double = Val(substrings(0))
    Dim sValueR As Double = Val(substrings(1))
    Dim tValueR As Double = Val(substrings(2))
```

Or You can take the Sum using:

```
 Dim overAllSum = dosage.Split("-").ToList().Where(Function(x) IsNumeric(x)).Sum(Function(y) Val(y))
```